# How to make nginx only accessible to <IP:Port> and not only <IP>?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am running a linux machine in a local network, on which nginx is installed and serving a static website (mkdocs).

I can connect to this static website from another PC (local network) when entering the linux machine's IP adress, which is something like 192.158.1.38. What I want to do however, is that the static website is **only** accessible under 192.158.1.38:8080 (or some port number), such that the IP could be used, for example, for another static website served from nginx using a different port.

What I did in nginx.conf is adding

```
http {
        server {
                listen 192.158.1.38:8080;
        }
...
}
```

and restarting nginx, but the behaviour is still the same: the site is reachable via 192.158.1.38, but not using 192.158.1.38:8080.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Edit /etc/ngix/ngix.conf (`listen 8080` and `listen [::] 8080` and restart ngix I remember vaguely.

Comment: If Nginx is reachable on port 80, it must be listening on port 80. Either you failed to restart Nginx, or there is another `server` block in there. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. `listen` does not need the IP address unless you have a multi-homed server and are limiting which NIC should be used.